# Converting SQL Query to IBatis/MyBatis Query

Tags: sql, oracle, mybatis, ibatis

I am new to `Ibatis` and still learning it.  I encountered this SQL query which needs to be converted in to an `Ibatis` query.

I tried putting in `CDATA` tag and tried some iterator tag also, but it didn't work out for me.  Here's my query:

```
SELECT comp_small_name
FROM table_company
WHERE companyid IN (
        SELECT agentid
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM table_comp_price
            WHERE companyid = #compid#
            ORDER BY companyid DESC
            WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
            )
        )
```

This is intended for an `Oracle` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Method 1`

```
SELECT comp_small_name
    FROM table_company
    WHERE companyid IN (
            SELECT agentid
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM table_comp_price
                WHERE companyid = #compid
                ORDER BY companyid DESC
                WHERE <![CDATA[ ROWNUM <= 2 ]]>
                )
            )
```

or you can also use as below `Method 2`:

```
 SELECT comp_small_name
    FROM table_company
    WHERE companyid IN (
            SELECT agentid
            FROM (
                SELECT *
                FROM table_comp_price
                WHERE companyid = #compid
                ORDER BY companyid DESC
                WHERE ROWNUM &lt;= 2
                )
            )
```